# When td is clicked change bgcolor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm having some issues here getting my html table to change a single `td` `

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table1 > td").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
table td.active {
    background: #006633;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0" id="table1">
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" height="20px" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>CULTURE</strong></td>
                    </tr>
               
                    <tr>
                    <td width="5%"><p align="center">1</p></td>
                    <td width="40%">Is the CDP obvious - You Said / We Did Boards; Feedback Stations; Posters?</td>
                    <td width="5%" height="20px"><p align="center">1</p></font></td>
                    <td width="5%" height="20px"><p align="center">2</p></font></td>
                    <td width="5%" height="20px"><p align="center">3</p></font></td>
                    <td width="5%" height="20px"><p align="center">4</p></font></td>
                    </tr>
    </table>
```

`when the`td` is clicked. For some reason when it is clicked it doesn't do anything. Anyone got any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: `td` is not direct child of the `table`. use `#table1 td` selector

Comment: No nothing in the console?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**.

Comment: `bgcolor`, seriously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#table1 > td")` to `$("#table1  td")`, but this will increase matches of your selection. So, I suggest adding a unique attribute (I encourage `data-*`).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*
    $("#table1 td").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    */
    // Better
    $("#table1 td[data-toggle]").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
table td.active {
    background: #006633;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0" id="table1">
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" height="20px" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>CULTURE</strong></td>
                    </tr>
               
                    <tr>
                    <td width="5%"><p align="center">1</p></td>
                    <td data-toggle width="40%">Is the CDP obvious - You Said / We Did Boards; Feedback Stations; Posters?</td>
                    <td data-toggle width="5%" height="20px"><p align="center">1</p></font></td>
                    <td data-toggle width="5%" height="20px"><p align="center">2</p></font></td>
                    <td data-toggle width="5%" height="20px"><p align="center">3</p></font></td>
                    <td data-toggle width="5%" height="20px"><p align="center">4</p></font></td>
                    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Okay this time I ran it and got an error in the browser console of: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: Ah fixed the console error was just a missing ". Anyway it's still not functioning just not doing anything?

Comment: Well, I have provided a working example (you can the snippet above) addressing your issue, and to solve it. If you want more help, you should update the question, or create jsFilddle or link me to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

$("#table1> td") means the td is the first child element in the table. This is not true, because this is the tr in your case. Simply change it to $("#table1 td") and you are done (remove the '>').

Answer (score 0):

change `$('#table1 > td')` to `$('#table1 td')` as `td` is not the first child of table1.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#table1 td").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
        });
    });
```

Here check the demo in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jagrati16/7ychbmht/